# display custom meta box on page

Tags: wordpress

i want to display the value of my metabox in the page template.
thanks advanced !!

this is the code of the metabox

```
function traduccion_add_custom_box() {
    $screens = array( 'page' );
    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'traduccion_sectionid',
            __( 'Inglés', 'traduccion_textdomain' ),
            'traduccion_inner_custom_box',
            $screen
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'traduccion_add_custom_box' );

function traduccion_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( 'traduccion_inner_custom_box', 'traduccion_inner_custom_box_nonce' );
  $ingles = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
  wp_editor( $ingles, 'traduccion_new_field' );
}
```

i m trying this in my page template but doesn't work

```
<?php
        $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID);
        $display_ingles = $custom['ingles'][0];
    ?>          

    <?php echo $display_ingles; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_post_meta` function is missing the meta_key variable, and if you set the single variable to true you don't need the [0]. The code should look like this:

```
<?php
    $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true);
    $display_ingles = $custom;

    echo $display_ingles;
?>
```